# A code that doesn't work on gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote a calculator program in visual studio. But i need it to run with also DEVC++. But my code doesn't work on gcc compiler. Here is a little part of the code that doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){

    long double var1 = 0, var2= 0, memory, result;
    char wordInput[50] = { 0 };
    char *endPtr1, *endPtr2;

    printf("Enter an input: ";
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", wordInput);

    var1 = strtold(wordInput, &endPtr1);
    printf("%.4f", var1);

}
```

This is the block of code where i get the input and convert it to double and assign to the var1. When i compile it with visual studio it works(it prints the number which is entered) but with devc++ it doesn't (it prints 0.0000). What can i do to fix it?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
     printf("Enter an input: ";
`

Comment: you have a missing closing bracket at the first `printf`

Comment: Not sure what version of Dev C++ you are using, but http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ is the one you want to use. This won't fix your code, but Orwell Dev C++ is the best "Dev C++" that there is.

Comment: I just forgot the bracket during the copy process. But thats not the case

Comment: I use the orwell. But thats not the case too, the problem is with the compiler.  I wrote this code with visual studio and it uses its own compiler i guess. But i need the code working on gcc too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdio.h>

....

    printf("%.4Lf", var1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Would you explain what that code does briefly. Im trying to learn

Comment: @TolgaŞen Some of the parameters for gcc is that in the standard it is set up to use the library of the VC for Windows does not work correctly. There is a macro for switching to a mode that does not use the library for that VC.

Comment: See also my answer (which explains the problem but doesn't provide the best solution, as yours does).

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** My answer explains the problem. [BLUEPIXY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710326/827263) provides what is probably the best solution.

---

DevC++ uses the MinGW port of gcc.  MinGW, by default, uses the gcc compiler along with Microsoft's runtime library.

The problem is that gcc and Microsoft's runtime library have a different idea of how the type `long double` is represented. When you print the value of `var1`:

```
printf("%.4f", var1);
```

you're passing a gcc-style `long double` value to Microsoft's `printf`, which expects a Microsoft-style `long double`. (One is 64 bits, the same size and representation as `double`; the other is larger, with more range and precision.) And you're also using an incorrect format. `%.4f` requires an argument of type `double`; you need `%.4Lf` to print a `long double`. Unfortunately, that doesn't help in this case because of the bug in MinGW.

As a workaround, you can convert the value of `var1` from `long double` to `double`, which both gcc and Microsoft's runtime library handle consistently:

```
printf("%.4f", (double)var1);
```

(This is not a bug in gcc or in Microsoft's runtime library, each of which is internally consistent. The size of `long double` is implementation-defined, and both implementations have made valid choices. It's a bug in MinGW's integration of these two components.)

Comment: Thank's for the explanation. I guess i got it. Sorry for not taking your answer up because question is already solved. But thank you so much for the explanation